# Xcode app thinning, how to reduce list of IPAs

Tags: ios, xcode, ipa, app-thinning

I try to generate IPAs for Ad Hoc distribution. I always select "All compatible device variants" for app thinning.

So, Xcode generates a lot of IPAs : Several versions of iPhone and iPad.

I would like to reduce the list of IPAs generated, for example by removing the iPad's IPA.
Xcode allow only to choose "All compatible device variants" or only one device.

Is it possible to select only the devices we want to choose ?

Answer (score 2):

Don't select any options("All compatible device variants" or any others), keep it None as default and go to the next page to generate .ipa file. Now its generate one IPA file only and it's compatible with all device.
[image: Check here]

[image]

Comment: So, it's all or nothing. Only one IPA file or all the IPA corresponding to all compatible device variants given by Xcode. It's not possible to select our own list of devices. Except by proceeding one by one, which is not a convenient solution.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't any idea about compatible devices selection or removing the iPads. sorry for that I can't understand your question properly

Answer (score 1):

When you publish your thinned app, an IPA is created for every configuration that your project supports.  **So if you've marked iPads and iPhones all the way back to iOS 8 and are shipping both armv7 and arm64 slices, you will end up with tons of IPAs at publish time.**  Limiting the number of IPAs involves using the Xcode project build settings to limit the configurations that your project builds

In Xcode, you'll want to go to

- Targets > General > Deployment Info
- Projects > Build Settings > Architectures > Supported Platforms

[image]
[image]

Comment: In Deployment Info, only iPhone is checked, but IPAs for iPad is always generated, why ? Supported Platforms contains iOS only. Moreover, is it a good practice to set "arm64 arm64e" only, inside Valid Architectures or is it better to let armv7 armv7s for more compatibility ?